# Problema com o CORS no Angular 5

Tags: web-service, angular, cors

Pessoal eu estou com uma aplicação teste em Angular 5 e estou tentando consumir o WebService do cartola. Ao realizar essa tentativa aparece o seguinte erro:

> Failed to load https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/status: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value 'https://cartolafc.globo.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Origin 'https://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access.

Eu sei que para questões de teste eu posso simplesmente desativar essa validação seja via plugin ou por outra opção. Mas e no caso de uma aplicação real. 
Por exemplo, eu vou criar essa aplicação e a mesma vai consumir o WebService do cartola. 
Como corrigir isso ?

Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Usuario } from '../model/usuario.model';
import { URL_API } from '../util/constantes';
import { Observable } from '../../../node_modules/rxjs';

const httpOptions = {
  headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'})
};

@Injectable()
export class UsuarioService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  public teste2(){
    return this.http.get('https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/status', httpOptions);
  }
}
```

Component:

```
// O botão no meu HTML chama esse método teste()
      public teste(): void{   
        this.serviceUsuario.teste2()
          .subscribe(
            (response) => {
              console.log("Sucesso");
              console.log(response);
            },
            err => {
              console.log("Erro");
              console.log(err);
            }
          )
      }
```

Comment: Aparentemente só está liberado a requisição para o próprio domínio https://cartolafc.globo.com/ Nesse caso sua aplicação deveria estar nesse domínio

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, precisamos entender o que é o CORS.

> Cross-origin resource sharing ou compartilhamento de recursos de origem cruzada é uma especificação de segurança de browsers que tem como intenção fazer a segurança de recursos de diferentes origens.

[Fonte](https://medium.com/@gigioSouza/resolvendo-o-problema-do-cors-com-angular-2-e-o-angular-cli-7f7cb7aab3c2).

A responsabilidade da configuração desse mecanismo é do backend. Ele que deve dizer quais domínios a API deve barrar/liberar o acesso.

Nesse caso, não temos acesso ao backend para adicionar o milagroso:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

E agora, como proceder?

Como você mencionou, pode-se utilizar uma extensão no Chrome para desabilitar o CORS, que vai funcionar em um ambiente de desenvolvimento. O problema é quando cai em produção, já que não temos controle sobre o browser do cliente.

Uma opção pra burlar esse controle é utilizar um *`reverse proxy`*, que deve monitorar as suas requisições e injetar os `headers` de CORS a cada requisição.

Existem várias formas de montar esse proxy, uma delas é bem descrita [nesse artigo](https://medium.com/@gigioSouza/resolvendo-o-problema-do-cors-com-angular-2-e-o-angular-cli-7f7cb7aab3c2), do qual retirei minha primeira citação.

Um serviço parecido com esse é o *[cors-anywhere](https://github.com/Rob--W/cors-anywhere/)*, que já disponibiliza um URL pronta para ser utilizada.

A requisição fica assim:

```
this.http.get('https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://api.cartolafc.globo.com/mercado/status').subscribe(r => {
  console.log(r);
}, err=> {
  console.log(err);
});
```

que retorna o objeto esperado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Funciona? Sim!

Deve ser usado?

Bom, na minha opinião, se o desenvolvedor da API negou esses acessos, é por algum motivo. Cabe a você decidir se o uso desse *workaround* é realmente necessário.