# Http Get retorna 200, mostra resultado no Fiddler, mas não traz o resultado no Angular 7

Tags: angular-7

Bom dia galera, estou com o seguinte problema, tenho uma api bem simples funcionando [API para teste](http://newageapi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/values). Quando faço uma requisição get pelo Angular
o retorno dá 200, trazendo o resultado, porém não consigo carregar esse resultado dentro do Angular. Vejam como eu fiz:

```
 //arquivo login.component
ngOnInit() {
    this.getValues();
 }
 getValues(): void {
    this.authService.getValues()
      .subscribe(dados => {
         console.log(dados)
    });
 }
```

no arquivo service.component

```
getValues(){
     return this.http.get('http://newageapi.us-east-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/api/values');  
}
```

Este é o resultado no fiddler:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este é o erro no Navegador Firefox
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segui o exemplo do projeto Hero do angular.io
Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Então Leonardo, o erro está bem claro: **Requisição cross-origin bloqueada**, isto é um erro de **`CORS`**, ou seja, você não tem permissão para acessar esses dados. Tem uma questão que vai te ajudar entender melhor sobre isso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/318049/problema-com-o-cors-no-angular-5

Comment: Pois é, mas o cors da api está liberando todos os acessos, tanto nas origens quantos os verbos. Se realmente estivesse bloqueando não retornaria 200 para o get, concorda? Inclusive ele manda um OPTIONS e depois envia um GET retornando os dados. No Postman funciona normalmente. Fiz o proxy e tmb não funcionou.